# Why does the chat recommendation email come from Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, support

This email comes from `"Server Fault" <do-not-reply@serverfault.com>`

> Hello!
>
> You registered for the following chat events happening today on chat.stackexchange.com:
>
> in 3 hours
>
> Recommendation chat
> in the room Mos Eisley -- enter this room | view events
> 7:00 PM UTC for 3h
>
> See you there!

Shouldn't this email be coming from SciFi StackExchange?

Answer (score 3):

It always comes from the site that you have set as your main site [in your profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble); in your case, that's Server Fault.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, by default, your main site in your chat profile is the one where you had the highest rep at the time of first signing into a chat.